# Using quote marks with NSURL and iOS8+

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I am trying to form a request using `NSURL`.
My code:

(somewhere)

```
#define CLASS_URL @"https://www.someurl.com/xyz"
```

(somewhere)

```
NSString *className = @"className";
```

Then my main code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&name=\"%@\"", CLASS_URL, className]];
```

I have read many answers on adding a quote mark on StackOverflow saying what I should use. I have tried :

- both `%22` and `%%22`
- adding `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`
- simply using `\"` as shown in the presented code

However none of the answers seem to be working. I am always getting `(null)` when calling `NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);`

Anyone has any idea on how to do this correctly?

**Edit:**
I tried using stringByAppendingString as suggested, still not working.

```
NSString *tmp = [CLASS_URL stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=\"%@\"",className]];
```

> Expected result:
>
> www.someurl.com/xyz&name="className"

I need double quotes in case user types a space.

Comment: which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: try this :NSString *strURL = [CLASS_URL stringByAppendingString:@"className"];

Comment: why are you using double quotes for the second %@ ? I am not sure but is there any purpose ?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @zaph

Comment: @Fengson As an aid to debugging break compound statements into multiple intermediate statements. In tjis case create the string and then convert to t URL, that way you are not fighting two pptential problems at once.

Comment: @Fengson, if you remove \ and double quotes for the second %@, you will get your expected result.

Comment: I have tried that and it works until I try to add \"

Comment: @Mr.T please provide a code. I need double quotes in case a user types a space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your expected URL is incorrect.

> I need double quotes in case user types a space.

Double-quoting does not make spaces legal in an URL. Spaces are reserved, and must be percent encoded, in quotes or not. Double-quotes are not part of the unreserved space, so should be quoted as well, if you needed them (but that wouldn't save you from encoding spaces).

The way to build this is to encode the string you want to send:

```
NSString *className = @"className with space";
NSString *quotedClassName = [className stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?name=%@", CLASS_URL, quotedClassName];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```

This will encode to:

```
https://www.someurl.com/xyz?name=className%20with%20space
```

Notice I've removed the double-quotes entirely. If you really need them, then you can get them by making your original string include them, and then encode them:

```
NSString *className = @"\"className with space\"";
NSString *quotedClassName = [className stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

This will encode to:

```
https://www.someurl.com/xyz?name=%22className%20with%20space%22
```

(I've also fixed your query parameter, which might just be a typo. The query is separated from the path by `?`, not `&`.)

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is deprecated in ios9.

Comment: when do we use ? and & in the query strings @RobNapier

Comment: @zaph Thanks; yeah I remember that whole kerfuffle now :D It really is a very good change; they should have done it in CFURL though…

Comment: @Mr.T `?` separates "hier-part" (path) from query. See RFC 3986 section 3. `&` isn't technically part of URLs at all. It's part of key/value data encoded using the `x-www-form-urlencoded` system. In common practice using HTTP, the query starts with `?` and is internally separated by `&`.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes in the URL need to be replaces with escaped quotes:

```
#define CLASS_URL @"https://www.someurl.com/xyz"

NSString *className = @"className";
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=\"%@\"", className];

// URL encode the query
query = [query stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", CLASS_URL, query];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```

> URL: https://www.someurl.com/xyz?name=%22className%22

Also the "&" needs to be replaced with `?`, query strings begin with a `?` and subsequent arguments are separated with '&'.